# Why I can not sftp into the huawei switch

Tags: switch, huawei

I have HUAWEI S2300 Switch, this is my configuration:

```
[HUAWEI-A]dis current-configuration
#
!Software Version V100R005C01
 sysname HUAWEI-A
#
 FTP server enable
#
 vlan batch 1 to 4 7 to 8
#
 cluster enable
 ntdp enable
 ntdp hop 16
 ndp enable
#
 dhcp enable
#
 undo http server enable
#
aaa
 authentication-scheme default
 authorization-scheme default
 accounting-scheme default
 domain default
 domain default_admin
 local-user admin password cipher !F&43ULTPTE*61\PR4!PYA!!
 local-user admin privilege level 3
 local-user admin service-type ftp
 local-user huawei password cipher N`C55QK<`=/Q=^Q`MAF4<1!!
 local-user huawei privilege level 3
 local-user huawei service-type ssh
 local-user root password cipher WY$\*-[*C3%*61\PR4!PYA!!
 local-user root privilege level 3
 local-user root service-type telnet ssh
#
interface Vlanif1
 ip address dhcp-alloc
#
interface Vlanif2
 ip address 10.10.11.32 255.255.255.0
#
...

#
 snmp-agent
 snmp-agent local-engineid 000007DB7F00000100006136
 snmp-agent sys-info version v3
#
 sftp server enable
 stelnet server enable
 ssh user admin
 ssh user huawei
 ssh user admin authentication-type password
 ssh user huawei authentication-type password
 ssh user admin service-type stelnet
 ssh user huawei service-type stelnet
#
user-interface maximum-vty 15
user-interface con 0
user-interface vty 0 4
 authentication-mode aaa
 protocol inbound ssh
user-interface vty 5 14
 authentication-mode aaa
#
```

You see I have created a `huawei` user use ssh, I can ssh login success use `huawei` account, but I can not sftp login it.

this is the information I use filezilla client:

```
response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
command:    open "huawei@10.10.11.32" 22
command:    Pass: ******
error:  Server sent disconnect message
error:  type 2 (protocol error):
error:  "The connection is closed by SSH server
error:  "
error:  cannot connect to server.
```

---

**edit-01**

I added the below configuration:

```
[Z306-LW-A-aaa]local-user huawei service-type telnet ssh ftp sftp
                                                             ^
Error:Too many parameters found at '^' position.
[Z306-LW-A-aaa]local-user huawei service-type telnet ssh ftp
```

there only can add the `telnet ssh ftp` , can not add `sftp`.

---

**Edit-02**

No matter I set the ftp directory to `flash:` or `flash:/`

```
local-user huawei service-type telnet ssh ftp
local-user huawei ftp-directory flash:
```

when I use filezilla connect there always come out this error:

```
Status: Unsecure server, does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: The server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Read directory listing...
Command: PWD
Response: 257 "flash:" is current directory.
Error: Unable to parse the returned path.
Error: Failed to read directory listing
```

Comment: (not a Huawei expert here, just curious): Does the user `huawei` have the _authorization_ to use sftp? It appears that `ssh user huawei service-type stelnet` is something like an _authorization_ command to use the `stelnet` service. Is there such a thing as `ssh user huawei service-type sftp` ?

Comment: See my edit post.

Comment: See exampes for the Sx700 series (I guess this applies to many series of Huawei switches) on https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000069520/d4061c3b/example-for-managing-files-using-sftp  

There _is_ such a thing as `ssh user <username> service-type sftp` and it probably needs to be complimented by `ssh user <username> sftp-directory <base-directory>:`

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

**SFTP** is supported by Huawei on most of switches models. Share your complete model number.

PS: By default, the SFTP service is disabled. You need to enable it.

Here is completed configuration of SFTP, You can see my configuration for help

```
#
 sysname SSH Server
#
aaa
 local-user client001 password cipher %$%$c|-D8KO4/,B[(FR.r!LHg]TK%$%$
 local-user client001 privilege level 15
 local-user client001 service-type ssh
#
sftp server enable
ssh user client001
ssh user client001 authentication-type password
ssh user client001 service-type sftp
ssh user client001 sftp-directory flash:
#
user-interface vty 0 4
 authentication-mode aaa
 protocol inbound ssh
#
return
```

Comment: There can not set `ssh user client001 service-type sftp `. seems only can set ftp.

Comment: share your  complete model number and Version details